# Did Rick Genest have a larger role in 47 Ronin?

Tags: character, 47-ronin

We see [Rick Genest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Genest) very briefly in *47 Ronin*. For basically a single scene I believe.

The movie poster lead me to beleive his was going to be a major part of the movie... Was there an entire plot line cut or deleted maybe?

(he's the guy with skull tattoo on his face)

[image]

Comment: is this was same for the official poster? this could be a fan made poster(IDK for sure)

Comment: To back @Vishwa's comment, I have seen movie at least 3 times. And there were no ships burning in them. However there was a burning scene but it wasn't the ships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Genest#As_an_actor_and_musician):

> due to various post-process tensions, stemming from the 2011 version of the film in which Universal executives wanted Reeves to become a more integral part of the film, Genest was largely edited out of the final version.

However, when I followed their link to [Variety](https://variety.com/2013/film/news/47-ronin-box-office-bomb-1201012170/) I was unable to find any mention of Genest.